# Why does Devise creates incorrect lost password POST path with custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I have a simple Devise install with a plain User model.  I confirmed it all worked (sign-up, lost passwords etc.) with the default routes then started to customize like this:

```
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]
  as :user do

     get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
     post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
     delete 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session

     get 'register/cancel' => 'devise/registrations#cancel', :as => :cancel_user_registration
     post 'register' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
     get 'register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
     get 'account' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration
     patch 'account' => 'devise/registrations#update'
     put 'account' => 'devise/registrations#update'
     delete 'account' => 'devise/registrations#destroy'

     post 'password' => 'devise/passwords#create', :as => :user_password
     get 'password/forgot' => 'devise/passwords#new', :as => :new_user_password
     get 'password/reset' => 'devise/passwords#edit', :as  => :edit_user_password
     patch 'password' => 'devise/passwords#update'
     put 'password' => 'devise/passwords#update'

  end
```

The forgot password page however creates a POST path like this:

```
<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/password.user" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
...
</form>
```

and from the coresponding view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
```

With the default Devise routes the url is properly displayed as `/users/password` but with my custom route I get `/password.user`.  It seems to just be this one route.

I know the easy fix is to just change `password_path(resource_name)` to `password_path` but I would like to understand why does this break in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging into the sources of Devise and a bit of experimenting, I think I have found out why this is happening. If you take a look at the routes generated by `devise_for` for a model `:user` the route for password has a prefix `user_password`. The route method for that is `user_password_path`. So how does actually the `password_path` works?

The `password_path` method that is called in the `new.html.erb` is not actually a method generated by `devise_for :user`. It is a helper method that takes the name of the model as an argument. When passed `:user` for example, it will look like this:

```
password_path(:user) => user_password_path
```

This method then calls the `user_password_path`, which is the correct one. More info [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/UrlHelpers).

In your case you are creating a route with a prefix `user_password`, but you also have these routes:

```
 patch 'password' => 'devise/passwords#update'
 put 'password' => 'devise/passwords#update'
```

that generate routes with prefix `password`. I guess this overrides/takes precedence over the `password_path` method in the `UrlHelper`.

About why it returns `/password.user`, each route method takes an optional format argument that specifies the format of the request (e.g. `/password.html`, `/password.json`, etc). In your case the `resource_name` has the value `user`.

What can you do? I suggest that you associate the `put` and `patch` methods with the `:edit_user_password` prefix, keeping the same structure as in the routes generated by devise. This way you won't override/hide the `password_path` method defined in the `UrlHelper` of devise.

Note: I had to restart my server at some points while experimenting with the routes. So if something is not happening as expected, try restarting it.